# How to subtract two int arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this array in Java:

```
private int[] all = new int [] {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

I want to set a new var that equal to `all-{2,3,5}` (equals {0,1,4})

Is there any build-in function that performs subtraction between two arrays?

Comment: What are you asking? You have shown them being removed from the array, not subtracted. What have you tried? Start with a loop.

Comment: No, there is not a built-in function for this with arrays. If you use `List<Integer>` instead, there is a `removeAll` method.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder ArrayList OR List???

Comment: [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is the standard implementation of the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. `List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 2):

You can code up set subtraction using Java 8 streams.

The idea is to construct a hash set of integers that you would like to exclude, and then run through the original array, check each element against the exclusion set in O(1), and keep only elements that should not be excluded.

```
int[] all=new int [] {0,1,2,3,4,5};
int[] ex=new int [] {2,3,5};
Set<Integer> exSet = IntStream.of(ex).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
int[] res = IntStream.of(all).filter(val -> !exSet.contains(val)).toArray();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/FscuFv)

Comment: @JONI6543 Please click demo link, and see import statements at the top. You need `java.util.stream.*`

Comment: i import java.util.streams.* but still "IntStream cannot be resolved"

Comment: @JONI6543 This is odd. Are you using Java compiler with version prior to 8?

Answer (score 2):

I understood what you want to say and figured out a way to do that , what exactly you want.
If you use ArrayList then you could use removerAll() to remove or subtract.
Lets see this on the working code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class removeAllInArrayList {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList <Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(0);
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(4);
    numbers.add(5);
    System.out.print("The number array contains:-  \t");
    display (numbers);

    ArrayList <Integer> numbers2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers2.add(0);
    numbers2.add(2);
    numbers2.add(4);
    numbers2.add(6);
    System.out.print("The number2 array contains:- \t ");
    display(numbers2);
    System.out.println("Subtract number2 from number.");
    numbers.removeAll(numbers2);
    System.out.print("Now, number array contains:-  \t");
    display (numbers);
}

public static void display (ArrayList array){
    for (int i =0 ; i < array.size() ; i++){
        System.out.print(array.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println ();
}

}
```

The result of the following code is

`The number array contains:-   0 1 2 3 4 5 
 The number2 array contains:-    0 2 4 6 
 Subtract number2 from number.
 Now, number array contains:-   1 3 5`

Hope this works , and helps to solve out the code.

Comment: Nice answer here, and I really appreciate your thoughtful and reasonable comeback on my suggestions to your other question!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a build-in method. You can try to find some library which can do that, or write your own method:

```
public static int[] removeEqual(int[] a_arr, int[] b_arr) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int a : a_arr) { list.add(a); }

    Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        int a = iter.next();
        for (int b : b_arr) {
            if (a == b) {iter.remove();}
        }
    }

    int[] result = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {result[i] = list.get(i);}

    return result;
}
```

Test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("expected: [0, 1, 4], actual: " +
            Arrays.toString(removeEqual(new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5}, new int[] {2, 3, 5})));
}
```

Output: expected: [0, 1, 4], actual: [0, 1, 4]

Comment: you not return a value

Comment: @JONI6543 fixed

Answer (score 0):

I tested Streams vs Collections:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] all = new int[100000];
    int[] ex = new int[50000];

    fillArrays(rand, all, ex);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    testWithStreams(all, ex);
    System.out.println(String.format("Streams: %d", System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

    fillArrays(rand, all, ex);// Avoid any external optimization
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    testWithCollections(all, ex);
    System.out.println(String.format("Collections: %d", System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

    fillArrays(rand, all, ex);// Avoid any external optimization
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    testWithCollectionsToArray(all, ex);
    System.out.println(String.format("Collections -> Array: %d", System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

    fillArrays(rand, all, ex);// Avoid any external optimization
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    testWithStreamsAndSet(all, ex);
    System.out.println(String.format("Streams + HashSet: %d", System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}

private static void fillArrays(Random rand, int[] all, int[] ex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
    {
        all[i] = rand.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ex.length; i++)
    {
        ex[i] = all[rand.nextInt(all.length)];
    }

//  System.out.println(String.format("all values: %d, %d, %d", all[0], all[1], all[2]));
//  System.out.println(String.format("ex values: %d, %d, %d", ex[0], ex[1], ex[2]));
}

private static int[] testWithStreams(int[] all, int[] ex)
{
    return Arrays.stream(all).filter(
            (elementOfAll) -> Arrays.stream(ex).noneMatch(
                    (elementOfEx) -> elementOfAll == elementOfEx
            )
    ).toArray();
}

private static List<Integer> testWithCollections(int[] all, int[] ex)
{
    List<Integer> listOfAll = Arrays.stream(all).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    listOfAll.removeAll(Arrays.stream(ex).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return listOfAll;
}

private static int[] testWithCollectionsToArray(int[] all, int[] ex)
{
    return testWithCollections(all, ex).stream().mapToInt((v) -> v).toArray();
}

private static int[] testWithStreamsAndSet(int[] all, int[] ex)
{
    HashSet<Integer> exSet = Arrays.stream(ex).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    return Arrays.stream(all).filter((element) -> !exSet.contains(element)).toArray();
}
```

The Output:

```
Streams: 13823
Collections: 2905
Collections -> Array: 2931
Streams + HashSet: 29
```

EDIT:
Added the example of [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with lists:

```
List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

List<Integer> toRemove = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5);

all.removeAll(toRemove);

System.out.println(all); // [0, 1, 4]
```

In order to be able to remove elements from the `all` list, you should create it with the `new ArrayList<>(anotherList)` constructor, since the lists returned by `Arrays.asList` cannot be structurally modified.